# Does closed immersion imply projective morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here $X\to Y$ is a projective morphism means: $X\to Y$ factors through a closed immersion $X\to \mathbb{P}_{Y}^{m}$, and then followed by the projection $\mathbb{P}^{m}_{Y}\to Y$. I have no idea how to find this $\mathbb{P}_{Y}^{m}$.

Comment: Are you asking whether a closed immersion is a projective morphism? In that case, you could just take $m = 1$, where projective space over $Y$ is just $Y$.

Comment: @Akhil: you mean zero, no?

Comment: @Mariano: Thanks, you're right.

Comment: @Akhil: Really? I know $Proj\mathbb{Z}[x_0]$ is an one element scheme, but it seems $Y\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Proj\mathbb{Z}[x_0]$ is not $Y$(though I don't know what it should be)?

Comment: Akhil is correct.  In order to see this, you might begin by convincing yourself that Proj $\mathbb Z[x_0]$ is *not* a one-element scheme.

Comment: I guess this follows from the fact: for any ring $R$,Proj$R[x]=D_{+}(x)=$Sepc$(R[x]_{(x)})=$Spec$(R)$. This also says every affine scheme is a projective scheme, which contradicts the intuition in varieties.

Answer (score 2):

A finite morphism is proper. So we know that a closed immersion is finite and therefore is proper.

Alternatively, just take $m = 0$ and then 
$$\mathbf{P}^0 = \textrm{Proj } \mathbf{Z} = \textrm{Spec } \mathbf{Z}$$

Comment: This is wrong. It should be $\mathrm{Proj}~\mathbf{Z}[x_0]$.